# best EDB for windows mobile 6.5 C# application

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I want to create EDB to existing windows mobile app at C#. I have found few solutions like:

- DbfDotNet there I have found a coordinator post about problem in this project. (http://dbfdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/283054)
- .NET and SQL Anywhere 10
- EDB from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912256 - but it is at C++ and I don't know how to use it at c#
- SQL Server CE - but "The latest release is the SQL Server Compact 4.0[1] supporting .NET Framework 4.0, and dropping support for Windows Mobile in this release."

Please can you give me advice and share your experiences? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Define EDB. Electronic Database? That could be whatever you feel like using. If you want SQL Server CE, can't you just use 3.5?

Comment: Embedded Database Engine. My task is to replace SQL CE by other EDB.

Comment: Would [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) work?

Comment: I guess yes. I will go this direction and when I will have solution I will probably answer my question :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried going down this route before, but I did not find a cut and dry solution for doing it.

So, I had a project I started on, but abandoned instead in favor of requiring my device to communicate directly with the SQL Server.

If communicating directly with the server is not an option for you, then one of your databases (either the local one on your device or the central one on the main server) is going to need a field to denote some form of Date Stamp and your device is going to need to keep track of this Date Stamp.

```
DateTime dateStamp; // on Windows Mobile

private void MockUp() {
  ReadDataFromServer();
  dateStamp = ReadDateFromServer();
  DoStuffInYourProgram();
  UpdateAnythingNewerThan(dateStamp);
}

private void ReadDataFromServer() {
  // read data from your central server
  // and store that data into a DataSet or DataTable
}

private DateTime ReadDateFromServer() {
  // this would be better in the ReadDataFromServer() method,
  // but it is shown here for clarity
}

private void DoStuffInYourProgram() {
  // This isn't a real routine, but rather what you are going
  // to have your device doing
}

private void UpdateAnythingNewerThan(DateTime value) {
  // read records from your server that are newer than the value
  // passed in, then update those values with the new data your
  // device has collected.
}
```

I wished I could be less vague, but that should give you the general idea.